# Protractor - Accessibility Test Results - Analyzing results

Tags: accessibility, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm using Accessibility Plugin + Protractor.

As listed below, I am seeing a few accessibility errors after running some smoke tests and I'm not sure, if the accessibility audit is actually performed in each webpage during the E2E Test.

As I am new to this, kindly advise if there is any way to trigger accessibility audit, after navigating to a new webpage during E2E Tests.

> **e2e-tests** **$**   grunt protractor:websiteSmokeTests
>   --website="https://testsite/"
>
> Running "protractor:websiteSmokeTests" (protractor) task Using the
>   selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub [launcher] Running 1
>   instances of WebDriver
>
> website home page functionality
>     Homepage - check invalid search return 0 Results - pass
>       Check Webmaster tools - BingSiteAuth and Google - pass
>       WebMaster Tools - Check Robots.txt  - pass
>
> website onpage feedback functionality
>        Check on page feedback for an Article - Give No - pass
>
> Finished in 28.875 seconds 8 tests, 101 assertions, 0 failure
>
> plugin: 0 (teardown)
>       Chrome A11Y - This element does not support ARIA roles, states and properties
>       Chrome A11Y - aria-owns should not be used if ownership is implicit in the DOM
>       Chrome A11Y - Elements with ARIA roles must be in the correct scope
>       Chrome A11Y - Audio elements should have controls
>       Chrome A11Y - This element has an invalid ARIA attribute
>       Chrome A11Y - ARIA state and property values must be valid
>
> ```
>     2 elements failed:
>     <div id="cookie-notice" class="notification" aria-describedby="cookieinfo">
>     <div class="cont ... " id="close-cookie-notification" class="close-notification">Close</button>
>     </div>
> </div>
>     <div id="decommissioned-site-notice" class="notification strong hidden" aria-describedby="decommissi ... -site-notification"
> ```
>
> class="close-notification">Close
>
> ```
>     https://github.com/GoogleChrome/accessibility-developer-tools/wiki/Audit-Rules#ax_aria_04
> Chrome A11Y - Elements with ARIA roles must use a valid, non-abstract ARIA role
> Chrome A11Y - Controls and media elements should have labels
> Chrome A11Y - An element's ID must be unique in the DOM
> Chrome A11Y - (WARNING) These elements are focusable but either invisible or obscured by another element (10 elements failed)
> Chrome A11Y - The web page should have the content's human language indicated in the markup
> Chrome A11Y - Images should have an alt attribute
> Chrome A11Y - (WARNING) The purpose of each link should be clear from the link text (3 elements failed)
> Chrome A11Y - (WARNING) Text elements should have a reasonable contrast ratio (4 elements failed)
> Chrome A11Y - role=main should only appear on significant elements
> Chrome A11Y - Meaningful images should not be used in element backgrounds
> Chrome A11Y - An element's ID must not be present in more that one aria-owns attribute at any time
> Chrome A11Y - ARIA attributes which refer to other elements by ID should refer to elements which exist in the DOM
>
>     2 elements failed:
>     <div id="cookie-notice" class="notification" aria-describedby="cookieinfo">
>     <div class="cont ... " id="close-cookie-notification" class="close-notification">Close</button>
>     </div>
> </div>
>     <div id="decommissioned-site-notice" class="notification strong hidden" aria-describedby="decommissi ... -site-notification"
> ```
>
> class="close-notification">Close
>
> ```
>     https://github.com/GoogleChrome/accessibility-developer-tools/wiki/Audit-Rules#ax_aria_02
>
> Chrome A11Y - This element has an unsupported ARIA attribute
>
>     2 elements failed:
>     <div id="cookie-notice" class="notification" aria-describedby="cookieinfo">
>     <div class="cont ... " id="close-cookie-notification" class="close-notification">Close</button>
>     </div>
> </div>
>     <div id="decommissioned-site-notice" class="notification strong hidden" aria-describedby="decommissi ... -site-notification"
> ```
>
> class="close-notification">Close
>
> ```
>     https://github.com/GoogleChrome/accessibility-developer-tools/wiki/Audit-Rules#ax_aria_10
> Chrome A11Y - Video elements should use <track> elements to provide captions [launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
> ```
>
> [launcher] chrome #1 failed 4 test(s) [launcher] overall: 4 failed
>   spec(s) [launcher] Process exited with error code 1
>
> Test failed but keep the grunt process alive.
>
> Done, without errors.

Answer (score 1):

When activated, the accessibility plugin runs alongside your existing protractor test and does audit each full page that your test hits. Even if your test lands on a page just to navigate to another and no functionality is executed along the way.

Side note: I'm having trouble getting the [ngHint plugin to run on my tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30513132/nghint-plugin-cannot-be-run-as-nghint-code-was-never-included-into-the-page). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The way to trigger an audit is to write tests that the Accessibility plugin can piggy-back onto...it doesn't crawl your site to run audits.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and so wrote a derivative of the protractor-accessibility-plugin: [protractor-axe-report-plugin](https://github.com/E1Edatatracker/protractor-axe-report-plugin). It only generates reports using the aXe engine, but can be run for multiple pages in your test.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to go your own and not use the accessibility plugin you're having difficulty with, [webaccessibility.com](https://webaccessibility.com/) has a free implementation example of 'Continuum for Protractor' that might be a good place to get started; you can use it to integrate automated accessibility testing into your existing Protractor tests, or easily write new ones. [Here's some more information](https://support.ssbbartgroup.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001007726-Access-Continuum-for-Protractor) if you're interested.