# ngHint plugin cannot be run as ngHint code was never included into the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plugins, protractor, angularjs-ng-hint

I've recently updated an AngularJS project to use Protractor 2.x and wanted to take advantage of the newly embedded plugins that come along with it. I was able to activate the timeline, console, and accessibility plugins without issue, but I keep getting the below error when trying to use the ngHint plugin.

What needs to be done to include the ngHint code into a page so it can run? The Protractor plugin documentation doesn't specify to do anything besides listing the plugin in the conf.js file.

[image: terminal output]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source code of the plugin](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/plugins/ngHint/index.js#L84), it can only mean one thing: `angular.hint` is not defined, which means angular-hint is not installed.

In other words, your angular application should have `ngHint.js` loaded.

As an example and a demo, see protractor [internal tests of the error message](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/45341c944bf60537849776c7f362ee0442b219e6/scripts/test.js#L121). It throws the error message with [noNgHint.html](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/testapp/ngHint/noNgHint.html), but works with [index.html](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/testapp/ngHint/index.html) (see there is angular-hint js loaded).

Comment: Thanks @alecxe . I'll see if I can figure it out.